# Prepping info for a data grid in Swift

Tags: swift, function

I'm making an app that will eventually have a second view controller that displays a grid of information from results of previous days. I've already worked out the app to gather the information I need, which would look as follows:

```
var s = 0
var d = 0
var h = 0.0
var m = 0.0
var date = NSDate()
```

So I'm wondering how I can run a function to prep these numbers to be used in a grid in a different view controller later on. There may be no other way to do it than to send it to an outside database, but I'd rather not do that. I think I'm going to want to use either a struct or a class maybe. Maybe I only need a dictionary? I don't know, but I'm going to want to save this information at the end of every day. I could write some psuedo code, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
func saveDailyResults() {
    ??? date = {
        s, d, h, m
    }

    allDates.append(){
        date
    }
}
```

I think what I'm looking for would be a way to make some thing like this:

```
var allResultsFromAllDays = [(2016-08-08, 2, 302, 2.3, 4.5),(2016-08-07, 1, 247, 2.4, 4.7),(2016-08-06, 3, 345, 2.9, 6.5)]
```

...Which I could append every day when new results come in.

I'd like to be able to later on build something that looks like this from the information. [image: Like this but Row would be date and Column would be s, d, h, m]
Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: You can use UITableView with Custom Data Cell, or to create programmatically labels or textfields using ScrollView as a background. Do you plan to edit data, do uou need to perform acrions on cell click???

Comment: I don't necessarily need actions on cell click, but I do need this information to be permanently in an accessible form somewhere.

Comment: And preferably editable later.

Comment: You can store the data locally on the device with NSUserDefaults. Or, if you want to share them between devices, with CloudKit. NSUserDefaults is a simple key-value storage, that should be ok for one record per day.

Comment: @jboi thanks that's helpful, but I have to somehow log the information in a variable the correct way. Do you know how?